# Iterate over two lists, compare items of the lists with a specific value

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I perform an `os.popen()` command to access a measurement stored in InfluxDB from the command line. The data is a table, but I am only concerned with two specific columns of the table, which is why I use `splitlines()`.
To display the specific two columns in the GUI, I use a `for` loop, and I strip the title line, store values of column 2 and column 3 in separate arrays as follows:

```
list_of_number = []
list_of_assigned = []
for line in output[1:]:
    self.cameraOutputTextEdit.append(line[2] + "    " + line[1])
    dict = {}
    dict['claimed'] = line[1]
    dict['eya_cam'] = line[2]
    list_of_assigned.append(dict['claimed'])
    list_of_number.append(dict['eya_cam'])

    print(list_of_assigned)
    print (list_of_number)
```

The print statements yield the output:

```
['claimed', '-------', 'false', 'true']
['eya_cam', '-------', '2', '1']
```

I now need to perform certain if conditions:

```
camNum = self.cameraNumber.text()
t="true"
f="false"
if (camNum in list_of_number and t in list_of assigned):
   do_something
if (camNum list_of_number and f in list_of assigned):
   do_something
if (camNum not in list_of_number):
   do_something
```

The issue with this is that when camera number '2' is given, it executes the first condition even though it has been assigned as 'false' in the Database.
Where am I going wrong with this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t in list_of_assigned
['claimed', '-------', 'false', 'true']
```

You are testing if the value `'true'` is in your `list_of_assigned`variable.  As long as there is one true in this list, `t in list_of_assigned` will always return true.  You should either zip these two tables and parse through them together in a loop or check the index of the camera in your `list_of_number` list then check if that index in `list_of_assigned` is true.

Comment: I tried the method of finding the index of the camera number and then checking if it is true/false in the second list at the same index position. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally typed `assigned` word?

```
if (camNum in list_of_number and t in list_of_assigned):
```

I think you may intent to write as above.